# Check data from tracking code Google Analytics - purchased items

Tags: google-analytics

I'm new to Google Analytics. I have the code embedded on the shop's website with function:  _gaq.push(['_addItem',. It tracks purchased items. The question is: where in the panel (reporting?) can I check data from this function?

Answer (score 0):

Conversions > Ecommerce > Product Performance